# Is there a lightweight editor for solidedge's .dft files

Tags: autocad, cad

I am looking for light weight editor for solid edge's(CAD) .dft files.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you would call it lightweight but their [2D drafting tool](http://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/en_us/products/velocity/solidedge/free2d/index.shtml) is free and will create and edit 2D files nicely.